# hg restart GUI mergetool after hg merge

Tags: mercurial, merge

Here is the scenario

```
1
|\
| \
2  3
| /
|/
4*
```

While doing hg merge, I got into 4* where I have conflicts in my files. Since I forgot to mention GUI tool, I now want to start a GUI tool

```
$ hg merge --tool meld
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges
```

So I can't seem to fix the issue without rolling back the conflict. Is there any way to do this?

In git I would easily do git mergetool and it would load a GUI anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hg resolve`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#resolve) to restart a merge. You can do

```
$ hg resolve foo
```

to restart the merge of just the `foo` file, or you can do

```
$ hg resolve --all
```

to restart the merge from scratch. Use

```
$ hg resolve --list
```

to see the progress of your merge — unresolved files are marked with an `U`.

Comment: Restart is the wrong word here, isn't it? You're not really restarting it, you're continuing it from where it last stopped/aborted?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: when you use `hg resolve` you are really restarting the merge from scratch (for that particular file). This means that Mercurial will dig out the original three files for the three-way merge and launch the merge program again. It used to be the case that `hg resolve` with no arguments would restart the overall marge — and throw away any manual resolved files you had! We now abort with a warning in that case.